# Equivalent for dlply in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I try to achieve the same what dlply does with `data.table`. So just as a very simple example:

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table( p = c("A", "B"), q = 1:2 )

dlply( dt, "p", identity )
$A
  p q
1 A 1

$B
  p q
1 B 2

dt[ , identity(.SD), by = p ]
   p q
1: A 1
2: B 2

foo <- function(x) as.list(x)
dt[ , foo(.SD), by = p ]
   p q
1: A 1
2: B 2
```

Obviously the return values of `foo` are collapsed to one `data.table`. And I don't want to use `dlply` because it passes the split `data.tables` as `data.frames` to `foo` which makes further data.table operations within `foo` inefficient.

Comment: plyr is a separate package that is meant for converting between different data structures with ease. data.table is implemented as an efficient/enhanced data.frame. That is its sole purpose. So there is no internal efficient method to do this. What you've showed already (lapply) is what one can do.

Comment: Why would you want to split a data.table? That goes against the whole purpose of using data.table (better efficiency by avoiding copies).

Comment: @Roland I totally agree. Maybe my example was not clear enough. What I actually want to do is performing on a series of data.table subsets some operations which construct in the end new `ReferenceClasses` objects which I want to return as a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more `data.table` oriented approach:

```
setkey(dt, p)
dt[, list(list(dt[J(.BY[[1]])])), by = p]$V1
#[[1]]
#   p q
#1: A 1
#
#[[2]]
#   p q
#1: B 2
```

There are more `data.table` style alternatives to the above but that seems to be the fastest - here's a comparison with `lapply`:

```
dt <- data.table( p = rep( LETTERS[1:25], 1E6), q = 25*1E6, key = "p" )
microbenchmark(dt[, list(list(dt[J(.BY[[1]])])), by = p]$V1, lapply(unique(dt$p), function(x) dt[x]), times = 10)
#Unit: seconds
#                                        expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#dt[, list(list(dt[J(.BY[[1]])])), by = p]$V1 1.111385 1.508594 1.717357 1.966694 2.108188    10
#     lapply(unique(dt$p), function(x) dt[x]) 1.871054 1.934865 2.216192 2.282428 2.367505    10
```

Comment: +1 for using `.BY`, which is one of those `.VAR`s I haven't learned how to use yet.

Comment: I don't like the syntax but this answers my question best.

Comment: just realized that `dt[, list(list( ... )), by = p]` is not only the best but perfect answer to my question. The result column `V1` may even contain objects of any type (primitives, S3, S4, ReferenceClasses objects, ...). That said, I hate the syntax even more :-)

Comment: @Beasterfield what exactly do you hate about the syntax? What did you expect instead or why is it not meeting your expectations?

Comment: Well, it's not that it's not as easy to use as `dlply` but aesthetically I like `dlply( dt, "id", foo )` better than `dt[ , list(list(foo(.SD))), by = id ]$V1`.

Comment: agreed, for this particular task `dlply` has a shorter expression - that's what you get when you specialize on one side, and ask for smth not-normally asked-for on the other; but if you have a suggestion on how you think this operation could fit better into the `data.table` syntax - I'd be curious to hear it

Comment: So funny, I ran today again in exactly the same problem and eventually found this _great_ question and even greater answer ;-) @eddi to answer your almost one year old comment, what about a syntax like `dt[ , foo, by = id, jAsList = TRUE ]`?

Comment: @Beasterfield I think some sort of customization of what happens to the results of `j` for each group is long over due. Some things that could happen are - what happens now, your suggestion of leaving it as a list, more advanced binding together, including non-matching columns, or matching out of order columns. I would highly encourage submitting a feature request about it.

Comment: @eddi I'm really sorry. I seem to be too stupid to create an rforge account. I'm afraid I am not able to submit a feature request somewhere else?

Comment: @Beasterfield :) ok, FR added - https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5679&group_id=240&atid=978

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
> split(dt, dt[["p"]])
$A
   p q
1: A 1

$B
   p q
1: B 2
```

Comment: Oh this was simple :-) I was just wondering about the performance, since split does not make use of `data.tables` syntax and capabilities. But your answer actually gave me the hint to the right direction. Many thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding G. Grothendieck's answer I was curious how well split performs:

```
dt <- data.table( p = rep( LETTERS[1:25], 1E6), q = 25*1E6, key = "p" )

system.time(
  ll <- split(dt, dt[ ,p ] )
)
  user  system elapsed 
  5.237   1.340   6.563 

system.time(
  ll <- lapply( unique(dt[,p]), function(x) dt[x] )
)
  user  system elapsed 
  1.179   0.363   1.541
```

So if there is no better answer, I'd stick with

```
lapply( unique(dt[,p]), function(x) dt[x] )
```